# Not able to ssh using newly created accounts

Tags: ssh, rhel, login

Help!

Having issue logging into an RHEL 7.9 server using newly created users. User has been added to `AllowUsers` of `sshd_config` and `sshd` service too.

Seems that user password not setting properly. Can anyone help? I tried searching for resolution and couldn't find anything yet. See below details. thanks

```
[root@server1 security]# useradd test1
[root@server1 security]# passwd test1
Changing password for user test1.
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@server1 security]# passwd -S test1
test1 LK 2021-08-26 7 90 7 30 (Password locked.)
[root@server1 security]# passwd -u test1
Unlocking password for user test1.
passwd: Warning: unlocked password would be empty.
passwd: Unsafe operation (use -f to force)
[root@server1 security]# passwd -uf test1
Unlocking password for user test1.
passwd: Success
[root@server1 security]# passwd -S test1
test1 NP 2021-08-26 7 90 7 30 (Empty password.)
[root@server1 security]# passwd test1
Changing password for user test1.
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@server1 security]# passwd -S test1
test1 NP 2021-08-26 7 90 7 30 (Empty password.)
[root@server1 security]# cat /etc/passwd | grep test1
test1:x:1011:1011::/home/test1:/bin/bash
[root@server1 security]# cat /etc/shadow | grep test1
test1::18865:7:90:7:30::
```

There's only one entry for UID `1101` -

```
awk -F: '$3=="1011"' /etc/passwd
```

Also, this is a standalone server. It doesn't use any external authentication system.

Comment: awk -F: '$3=="1011"' /etc/passwd - I checked this and there is only one line.

Comment: Also, this is a standalone server. It doesn't use any external authentication system.

Comment: it's  rhel 7.9 .......

Comment: Have you added or changed anything in `/etc/pam.d`? Added any non-default PAM authorisation/authentication modules?

Comment: Set `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restart and see the output.

Comment: @roaima, Actually this vm was handed over to us by a different team with one OS user account with it (user with root access). we still use given account since cannot create any user :(. I didn't do any modification to /etc/pam.d. I'm checking with other team find out if they done have any modifications.